cat( sprintf() ) is not producing output in console in RStudio, or in native execution in Windows environ
I have this section of code which has been producing output for years from an aggregated df, and then recently, I find out that it is not producing the output.  I do use sinks() to direct the output to a file, but a also use "split = T".  I have tried closing the sinks() and restarting R. Any suggestions?
  nHCCICD10 <- dim(result)[1]
  
  for( i in 1:nHCCICD10 ) {
    cat( sprintf("%8.0f\t%30.30s\t%10.10s\t%45.45s\n", # \t%10.3f\n",
                 result[i,]$HCC,
                 result[i,]$HccDescription,
                 result[i,]$ICD.10,
                 result[i,]$DX_DESC
                 # result$RAF[i] 
    ))
  }
  cat( "\n\n" )

  # empty output

dim(result)
# [1] 11  6

Probably an R version issue.  I update sporadically:
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)"
> 
> 
> 
> RStudio.Version()
$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘2024.4.2.764’

$long_version
[1] "2024.04.2+764"

$release_name
[1] "Chocolate Cosmos"

Here is some sample code to produce the df:
library(dplyr)

# Create the DataFrame
result <- data.frame(
  result = c("D5700", "D571", "D5740", "D57419", "D61818", "I2720", "I2721", "E6601", "Z6841", "D696", "N1831"),
  ICD.10 = c("D5700", "D571", "D5740", "D57419", "D61818", "I2720", "I2721", "E6601", "Z6841", "D696", "N1831"),
  Model = rep("V24", 11),
  HCC = c(46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 85, 85, 22, 22, 48, 138),
  HCCDescrip = c(
    "Severe Hematological Disorders",
    "Severe Hematological Disorders",
    "Severe Hematological Disorders",
    "Severe Hematological Disorders",
    "Disorders of Immunity",
    "Congestive Heart Failure",
    "Congestive Heart Failure",
    "Morbid Obesity",
    "Morbid Obesity",
    "Coagulation Defects and Other Specified Hematological Disorders",
    "Chronic Kidney Disease, Moderate (Stage 3)"
  ),
  DX_DESC = c(
    "Hb-SS disease with crisis, unspecified",
    "Sickle-cell disease without crisis",
    "Sickle-cell thalassemia without crisis",
    "Sickle-cell thalassemia, unspecified, with crisis",
    "Other pancytopenia",
    "Pulmonary hypertension, unspecified",
    "Secondary pulmonary arterial hypertension",
    "Morbid (severe) obesity due to excess calories",
    "Body mass index [BMI] 40.0-44.9, adult",
    "Thrombocytopenia, unspecified",
    "Chronic kidney disease, stage 3a"
  ),
  RAF = c(1.372, 1.372, 1.372, 1.372, 0.665, 0.331, 0.331, 0.250, 0.250, 0.192, 0.069),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)


Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of dput(head(result)).

Given the posted data, 1) it's not result[i,]$HCC, it's df[i,]$HCC; 2) the 2nd correct column name in the loop is df[i,]$HCCDescrip

Unrelated: I find df[i,]$HCCDescrip ugly, much better is df$HCCDescrip[i]. This is not only a matter of personal taste, R's data.frames are lists of column vectors and it's much more eficient to extract the column first, then its elements.

The problem is that you have the wrong column name in one spot:  you have HccDescription in your code, and HCCDescrip in your data.  That makes one of the arguments to sprintf() a NULL, which makes the whole result be character(0).

Good eye, user2554330... you are exactly right.  I have been using this code for several years... so it all looks the same to me,  and I never noticed when I introduced that column name discrepancy.  Thank you.
